# How to deploy build folder of React JS on nginx server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, nginx, deployment

Is React JS is dependent on [node-server](https://www.quora.com/Does-React-require-Node-js)? I have created a react js simple app using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app).To deploy build folder on Nginx server which is running on Ubuntu 16, i just moved the complete build folder to nginx html folder.

After restarting nginx server if i try to hit desired url site is not rendering.But if i try to run react js app on development mode by opening the port whole app is rendering.

In this case does react js really needs a node environment to publish app to production.To just serve that build folder it is mandatory to dependent on node js server.

How to overcome this problem.For deploying react app on nginx server followed below links

- [Create react app deployment](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#deployment)
- [Zero Configuration](https://blog.heroku.com/deploying-react-with-zero-configuration)
- [Serving Node JS  on Ubuntu](http://.https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04)

What is the proper way to deploy react js app on nginx server without node js

PS: Rendering statics from build folder - [Exact Issue Link here](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/527)

Comment: You should put what's inside of your build folder to your nginx folder. Or try to access it from `yourwebsite.com/build` or `yourwebsite.com/build/index.html`, depends on your nginx config.

Comment: I tried that way it was not working @Walk

Comment: What about other html files? Do they work when you move them to nginx folder? It shouldn't be different.

Comment: @Walk i have single html file  others are components those are created as bundle.js and added as script to index.html

Comment: Sure, I mean what about other html files, not for your react app, just regular html files, do they work?

Comment: Yeah @Walk they are working perfectly no issues in that

Comment: React pages are just html and javascript. You can start by troubleshooting whether your app's html file is being served at all, and then whether your javascript is getting loaded at all. "View source." Can you be more specific than "not rendering?" What is happening?

Comment: @skypecakes not able to render static files from build folder https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/527